# What permission is needed for udp in a chrome app?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-app

What permission is needed for udp in a chrome app?
I get the error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running sockets.udp.bind: App does not have permission

but I can't find the permission needed.
My manifest.json file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "XX",
"description": "XX",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
},
"sockets": {
    "udp": {
        "send": "*"
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "fullscreen", "alwaysOnTopWindows", "videoCapture", "storage", "browser"
]
```

}

Answer (score 4):

you need to ask for the bind permission

```
"udp": {
      "send": ["*"],
      "bind": ["*"]
}
```

Comment: This is the actual answer, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Using UDP

Chrome Apps can make connections to any service that supports UDP.
Sending data

Here's a sample showing how to send data (sockets.udp.send) over the network using UDP:

```
// Create the Socket
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
  // The socket is created, now we can send some data
  var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
  chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
    '127.0.0.1', 1337, function(sendInfo) {
      console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
  });
});
```

Receiving data

This example is very similar to the 'Sending data' example, except we setup an event handler for receiving data.

var socketId;

```
// Handle the "onReceive" event.
var onReceive = function(info) {
  if (info.socketId !== socketId)
    return;
  console.log(info.data);
};

// Create the Socket
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
  socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
  // Setup event handler and bind socket.
  chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(onReceive);
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId,
    "0.0.0.0", 0, function(result) {
      if (result < 0) {
        console.log("Error binding socket.");
        return;
      }
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
        '127.0.0.1', 1337, function(sendInfo) {
          console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
      });
  });
});
```

for more info: [look here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network)

Comment: Yeah, nice copy-pasting, @Denial. (No offence)
But this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: of-course i did copy paste...but these answered helped me...anyway good luck